# Send node path alias to user

Tags: rules, path-aliases

When I create a new content, I would like to send an email that contains "node path alias".

#### Pathauto pattern

```
[title-raw]-[nid]
```

#### Rules

```
ON event After saving new content  
IF
Created content is Les entreprises  
AND  
Created content is new
Add a condition
DO
Send a mail to a user
```

#### Rules email

```
[node:node-path]
```

I receive the email, but the content is 'node/16565'. I would like to receive 'les-entreprises-16565'.

If I inspect token with the Devel module, I get: node-path (String, 21 characters) les-entreprises-16565.

Why didn't I receive this node path alias? Is the Rules module sending the mail too quickly, and the path alias is not yet created?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the condition “Entity is of type … Node”? Having to specify this condition may seem redundant, since you have already established this rule is triggered by the Event “After saving new content”. However, I have experienced that without this condition a very limited amount of tokens holding data from the node will be available to the Action and any Components invoked by the rule.
 Good Luck!
Susan